# Android device not capable of receive on DatagramSocket

Tags: android, sockets

I have two Android Devices, one with IP address 10.0.0.6 and another 10.0.0.9  I can ping both of them on my computer.

I send out a broadcast message from 10.0.0.6 UDP package and verified that with my wireshark,

the broadcast address is 10.0.0.255

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(3400);

```
    socket.setBroadcast(true);

    byte[] buf = ("Hello from Android").getBytes();


    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length,  getBroadcastAddress(), 3400);

    socket.send(packet);
```

However, my other android device didn't receive anything from that broadcast message.

DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(3400);

```
            byte[] buf = new byte[30];

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

            socket.receive(packet);
```

It never come back from socket.receive.

Comment: Does it work if you don't use a broadcast, but address the packet directly to the device?

Comment: Are there any routers in the way on your LAN? UDP broadcast is blocked by default by most routers.